# Solve a pair of coupled nonlinear equations within certain limits

Tags: optimization, python, nonlinear-equations, constrained-optimization, scipy

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8739526/2623899) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8739227/2623899) works only for situations in which the desired solution to the coupled functions is not restricted to a certain range.

But what if, for example, we wanted a solution such that `0 < x < 10` and `0 < y < 10`?

There are functions within [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) that find roots to a function within a given interval (e.g., [`brentq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq)), but these work only for functions of **one variable**.

Why does `scipy` fall short of providing a root solver that works for multi-variable functions within specific ranges?  How might such a solver be implemented?

Comment: Transform your variables so they remain restricted.

Comment: Numerical Recipes has a good discussion on multivariate root finding, and all the evilness that an extra dimension adds that you can trip on.

Answer (score 1):

This is multivariate optimization with bound constraints (if you want to look it up in the literature). The [TAO](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/tao/) software can solve these problems if you want true optimization. If all you want is the solution of nonlinear equations with bounds, you can use the SNESVI solver in [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/petsc/).